# Taylor's formula in several

Tags: taylor-expansion

What i'm puzzling about is this:

I use the following form of Taylor's formula with integral remainder term:
For a smooth function $\varphi$ it holds that

$$
\varphi(x+h) = \varphi(x) + \int_0^1 \varphi'(x+\theta h) h \,d\theta.
$$

Next, let us consider $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R} \ni (x,y) \mapsto f(x,y)$ with
$f(x,\cdot)$ and $f(\cdot,y)$ being continuously differentiable for every $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $y\in \mathbb{R}$ respectively.

Now we fix $x,y, h_2\in \mathbb{R}$. Then Taylor's formula yields
$$
f(x+h_1,y+h_2) = f(x,y+h_2) + \int_0^1 \partial_x f(x+\theta_1 h_1,y+h_2)\,h_1\,d\theta_1 
$$
for every $h_1 \in \mathbb{R}$ and on the other hand for $x,y$ fix we have
$$
f(x,y+h_2) = f(x,y) + \int_0^1 \partial_y f(x,y+\theta_2 h_2) \,h_2\,d\theta_2.
$$
All told, we obtain
$$
f(x+h_1,y+h_2) = f(x,y) + \int_0^1 \partial_x f(x+\theta_1 h_1,y+h_2)\,h_1\,d\theta_1 
+ \int_0^1 \partial_y f(x,y+\theta_2 h_2) \,h_2\,d\theta_2
$$
for every $h_1,h_2 \in \mathbb{R}$.

I tried to verify this for $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$, but it seems that it doesn't work. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Let's compute:

$$\begin{align}
f(x,y) &+ \int_0^1 \partial_x f(x+\theta_1h_1,y+h_2)h_1\,d\theta_1 + \int_0^1 \partial_y f(x,y+\theta_2h_2)h_2\,d\theta_2\\
&= x^2+y^2 + \int_0^1 2(x+\theta_1h_1)h_1\,d\theta_1 + \int_0^1 2(y+\theta_2h_2)h_2\,d\theta_2\\
&= x^2+y^2 + 2xh_1 + 2yh_2 + h_i^2\int_0^12\theta_1\,d\theta_1 + h_2^2\int_0^1 2\theta_2\,d\theta_2\\
&= x^2 + y^2 + 2xh_1 + 2yh_2 + h_1^2 + h_2^2\\
&= (x+h_1)^2 + (y+h_2)^2\\
&= f(x+h_1,y+h_2).
\end{align}$$

It's correct, it works, you probably have only made a mistake in evaluating the integrals.

Answer (score 0):

You miss the cross derivative. I shall try to explain this : a first order Taylor expansion approximates a function of one variable by a straight line. A first order Taylor expansion approximates a function of two variables by a plane which means that f[x,y] is approximated by A + B (x - x0) + C (y - y0) + D (x -x0) (y - y0) which is bilinear with respect to x and y. I hope and wish this helps you. I let you finding what are A, B, C, D.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I always thought that a term like D(x-x0)(y-y0) would first appear in a second order Taylor expansion. Regarding my question i have to say that i was looking for a "zero" order Taylor expansion. A direct application of Taylor's formula for several variables would give the remainder
integral term $$
\int_0^1 \partial_x f(x+\theta h_1, y+ \theta h_2)\,h_1 + \partial_y f(x+\theta h_1, y+ \theta h_2) \,h_2 \,d\theta
$$

Comment: @rokeby.It is not second order : it is first order with respect to x and first order with respect to y.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici It's $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}$, a second derivative.

Comment: @DanielFischer. This is a very good question, indeed ! I am a physicist, not a mathematician. Let us suppose that a phenomenon is linear with respect to X and Y; then, the complete approximation is a X + b Y + c X Y. This is why I gave this answer. Please, tell me if I am wrong. I shall not be ashamed of that (at my age ...!). Thanks.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici The first order (linear) approximation is $aX + bY$. The second order approximation contains the bilinear part $cX^2 + dXY + eY^2$ in addition to the linear part.

Comment: Ah, j'ai vu que vous êtes Palois. Quelle fortune, si près des Pyrénées. I envy you ;)

Comment: @DanielFischer. Here, I disagree (and accept to be wrong, for sure) : Z = a + b X + c Y + d X Y is linear in both directions. This is a typical problem in multivariable linear regression. But, again, I am not a mathematician and I totally accept your points.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici It's separately linear (affine, rather), but not jointly. The part $dXY$ is $O(\lVert X\rVert\cdot \lVert Y\rVert)$, hence $O(\lVert X\rVert^2 + \lVert Y\rVert^2)$. For the first order Taylor approximation one uses only $\partial_x f$ and $\partial_y f$, $Z = a + bX + cY + o(\lVert (X,Y)\rVert)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer.At this point, I surrender ! I really thank you.

Comment: @DanielFischer. This is the problem : we almost never know where people are located. So, if I may ask, where are you and what are you doing (math, I bet but where ?). :)- Merci du message en français.

Comment: @DanielFischer. Please execute the following command with Mathematica : Normal[Series[F[x, y], {x, x0, 1}, {y, y0, 1}]] and please come back to me.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici D'abord, excusez, your query about the location fell under the radar, I'm from Bremen, Allemagne du nord. Then, I don't have Mathematica, but looking at the [online documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Series.html), "Series[f, {x, x0, nx}, {y, y0, ny}, ...]
successively finds series expansions with respect to x, then y, etc.", that would expand the first order series with respect to x, $f(0,y) + f_x(0,y)\cdot x + o(x)$, to a first order approximation with respect to $y$, each term independently, if I understand correctly.